# how to make my own linux kernel driver closed(not open source)?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Hi I have driver but I want make it proprietary, How can I do it. Is it possible to make my driver as a .so and I will create a wrapper driver. thru wrapper driver can I access my .so lib.

Comment: Do you intend to distribute it? I'd highly recommend not making your driver closed source or you'll find yourself in a lot of trouble keeping it up to date with the latest kernel.

Comment: @tangrs, _with the latest kernel_? It should be available with every single kernel configuration there is!

Comment: In that case you're probably going into world of hurt. First, you should know that inside the kernel, there's no such thing as a stable ABI or backwards compatibility so you'll be updating your driver often (and given the pace of kernel development, I doubt you'd be able to keep up). Secondly, because there's no stable ABI, a binary compiled for one kernel (I'm assuming by proprietary, you won't be distributing source code) may completely break on another - even if it's the exact same version and configured with the same options. Even using a different compiler will change how it's built.

Comment: There's not many people in the world who can keep a out-of-tree module up to date with the latest kernel. Nvidia is one such organization but keep in mind that they have a lot more resources than you. Then there are all the legal issues surrounding whether distributing proprietary kernel modules is allowed under the GPL. See Shahbaz's excellent answer.

Comment: It halfway sounds like you might be wanting to create a sort of user-mode driver where most of the code would run as a userspace daemon, utilizing either an existing thin interface in the kernel, or more problematically a new one.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. If you write your driver for the Linux kernel, it means it's "derived" from the Linux kernel<sup>1</sup>. The Linux kernel is under GPLv2, which implies that any derivative work of a GPL-licensed code must also have a GPL-compatible license.

In other words, if you write a driver for the Linux kernel and you distribute its binary, you have to distribute its source code too if anyone asks for it. Thus your driver would have to be free. Note that this is free as in "free speech", not "free beer", i.e. you could still sell your driver, but you cannot restrict anyone from publishing its source code for free.

This is beside the hell you would be putting yourself through to avoid compiling the module on the target Linux kernel. You'd basically have to get the configuration file for each machine you want your driver to be installed, compile a kernel with that exact configuration, compile your driver on it and then pass the binary (which is nonetheless illegal).

---

<sup>1</sup> If I had understood correctly, if your driver was originally written for another operating system and you just port it to the Linux kernel, then it's not considered "derivative work"<sup>2</sup> and your hands would be a bit freer<sup>3</sup>. I think this is one of the differences between GPLv2 and GPLv3 and one of the reasons GPLv3 was not adopted in the Linux kernel.

---

<sup>2</sup> When reading the note below, bear in mind that Linus means "derivative work", not "derived work" (http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/Law/derivative.html).

---

<sup>3</sup> http://linux.sys-con.com/node/38143:

> > I have heard many people reference the fact that the although the Linux
> >     Kernel is under the GNU GPL license, that the code is licensed with an
> >     exception clause that says binary loadable modules do not have to be
> >     under the GPL.
>
> ---
>
> Nope. No such exception exists.
>
> There's a clarification that user-space programs that use the standard
>   system call interfaces aren't considered derived works, but even that
>   isn't an "exception" - it's just a statement of a border of what is
>   clearly considered a "derived work". User programs are *clearly* not
>   derived works of the kernel, and as such whatever the kernel license
>   is just doesn't matter.
>
> And in fact, when it comes to modules, the GPL issue is exactly the
>   same. The kernel *is* GPL. No ifs, buts and maybe's about it. As a
>   result, anything that is a derived work has to be GPL'd. It's that
>   simple.
>
> Now, the "derived work" issue in copyright law is the only thing that
>   leads to any gray areas. There are areas that are not gray at all:
>   user space is clearly not a derived work, while kernel patches clearly
>   *are* derived works.
>
> But one gray area in particular is something like a driver that was
>   originally written for another operating system (ie clearly not a
>   derived work of Linux in origin). At exactly what point does it become
>   a derived work of the kernel (and thus fall under the GPL)?
>
> THAT is a gray area, and *that* is the area where I personally believe
>   that some modules may be considered to not be derived works simply
>   because they weren't designed for Linux and don't depend on any
>   special Linux behaviour.
>
> Basically:
>
> > anything that was written with Linux in mind (whether it then *also*
> >     works on other operating systems or not) is clearly partially a derived
> >     work.
> >     anything that has knowledge of and plays with fundamental internal
> >     Linux behaviour is clearly a derived work. If you need to muck around
> >     with core code, you're derived, no question about it.
>
> Historically, there's been things like the original Andrew filesystem
>   module: a standard filesystem that really wasn't written for Linux in
>   the first place, and just implements a UNIX filesystem. Is that
>   derived just because it got ported to Linux that had a reasonably
>   similar VFS interface to what other UNIXes did? Personally, I didn't
>   feel that I could make that judgment call. Maybe it was, maybe it
>   wasn't, but it clearly is a gray area.
>
> Personally, I think that case wasn't a derived work, and I was willing
>   to tell the AFS guys so.
>
> Does that mean that any kernel module is automatically not a derived
>   work? HELL NO! It has nothing to do with modules per se, except that
>   non-modules clearly are derived works (if they are so central to the
>   kernel that you can't load them as a module, they are clearly derived
>   works just by virtue of being very intimate - and because the GPL
>   expressly mentions linking).
>
> So being a module is not a sign of not being a derived work. It's just
>   one sign that *maybe* it might have other arguments for why it isn't
>   derived.
>
> Linus

and http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Kernel/proprietary-kernel-modules.html:

> > Some weeks ago, I posted an article on a probable violation of the GPL.
> >     It was about a device driver for a frame grabber that could be
> >     dynamically linked with Linux or statically linked with it.
> >
> > Some people, namely Linus himself, stated that it was fair use of
> >     the GPLd code (the kernel), because no line of code was apparently
> >     used, and the driver was independent enough.
> >
> > I'm not a lawyer, but I cannot accept this interpretation of code reuse.
> >     A device driver is not in any way independent of the kernel with which
> >     it interacts. I'm not talking about interface copyright or patents, but
> >     about logical dependence.
>
> ---
>
> Note that there is no such thing as "dynamically link into the kernel"
>   in Linux. Instead there are "loadable modules".
>
> Now the above may strike some people as nit-picking, but there is one
>   rather important thing about loadable modules: they can not link
>   themselves against any random kernel routine. And the routines they
>   can link against are routines that I consider to be "logically
>   independent" of the kernel implementation.
>
> Essentially, the kernel module interface is a "library" interface to
>   the kernel, and kernel modules are considered to be under the GNU
>   Library license. In fact, due to the way kernel modules work, you
>   automatically do it according to the LGPL, so this isn't explicitly
>   stated anywhere, but that's the way you should think about this.
>
> Another way to look at this — using the legal rather than the moral
>   viewpoint — is to just see module loading as "use" of the kernel,
>   rather than as linking against it. I prefer to explain the rationale
>   behind it using the moral reason to do it, though:
>
> The reason the kernel is exposed in such a LGPLd way when using
>   modules is simply that there are a lot of kernel device drivers for
>   Unix available, and they were not all written under Linux. If somebody
>   wants to port his SVR4 driver to Linux but doesn't want to GPL it, I
>   feel that he should have the right to do that, using modules. After
>   all, the driver wasn't actually derived from Linux itself: it's a real
>   driver in its own right, so I don't feel that I have the moral right
>   to force him to switch copyrights.
>
> Now, the above said, I much much prefer GPLd drivers, even if they are
>   available only as modules. Especially if they were actually originally
>   written for Linux, I consider it a bit dodgy to not use the GPL (they
>   can potentially be considered derived works, even if you don't
>   actually link them into the kernel, per se). But I do not want to
>   force it on people that arguably are not doing derived work. (It would
>   be rather preposterous to call the Andrew FileSystem a "derived work"
>   of Linux, for example, so I think it's perfectly OK to have a AFS
>   module, for example.)
>
> For several reasons, a Linux module also doesn't always make much
>   sense unless it comes with sources — if some commercial company thinks
>   that Linux is important enough that they want to do a commercial
>   module for Linux, they may also recognize that a binary module doesn't
>   work for most Linux users who use experimental kernels, for example.
>
> Final note: the Linux interpretation is not a "normal" case. I
>   wouldn't use it as a guide-line to anything else, especially not in
>   user mode.
>
> Linus

Comment: Any reason for a downvote? I'm not a lawyer, so the information may not be entirely precise. I'd appreciate an input so I'd learn too.

Comment: what about what companies like nvidia do, distributing driver binaries?

Comment: Pretty sure nVidia distributes source code for a wrapper layer which is compiled into a kernel module on the user's system upon installation. That wrapper layer wraps around the actual driver which is a binary blob. Even still, nVidia has to keep up with the latest kernel for their wrapper layer.

Comment: @hemerly, nvidia doesn't distribute binary. it distribute a self extracting bash script that extracts the code and compiles it. I've seen the code myself because I had to fix a build issues with kernel 3.11 just as Ubuntu 13.10 came out.

Comment: @hemerly, correction: the nvidia driver is a mixture of linux-specific source code that gets compiled and a portable binary blob that gets linked into it. The reason Linus allows this is that avcording to GPL, any _derived_ code from the kernel (which is GPL) must be free, but the nvidia driver was derived from windowsand ported to Linux, so it's not a _derived_ work. Stallman doesn't agree by the way, so this is at best a gray area.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have not a clear idea about open/closed source.

Fast description:

**Open**: do your driver and distribute the source code

**Close**: do your driver, compile it and distribute the compiled file

In your case, you have to distribute the **.ko** file. As tangrs said, you will have trouble for every kernel relase. For every release, you have to recompile the driver and distribute it.

Can you make a **.so** file? No, because you are writing a kernel driver and not a library (as you said).

Comment: And even for every release, depending on the compilers used and the user's configuration, it might not work on the end user's system anyway.

Comment: yep, lot of troubles :)